# Adding a delimited text layer in QGIS 1.8 only imports a fraction of the total rows

Tags: qgis

I am trying to add a delimited text layer, and I think I've formatted it correctly as a CSV file. There are no errors when I import the data. But even though there are 1300 rows total, only 189 appear in the table when I right click on the layer and open the attribute table. Is there any reason why it would import so few rows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a good chance that there are commas within some of your text fields. Even if the commas are surrounded by quotes, the delimiter plugin will parse a string into separate fields. These records will not be imported into your vector layer.

As an example, look at the second record in the 'text' field in the csv file below. It contains a comma within the string.

[image]

When you try to create your layer, the comma between "a,bc" is parsed as two different fields without an error message.

[image]

.. and the record with the comma is not included in the output:

[image]

You might try saving your file using a different delimiter. I often use "|" myself.

Hope that helps,

Cyrus